# Unable to get child class values with query using Hibernate Table Per Class Hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, class

I have 2 java classes with hibernate defined classes defining the parent/child relationship with the "extends" keyword for a single table.
I have a LONGTEXT field in the table defining which type of child class that record is relational to. (Table per class hierarchy)

I am wanting to query the table and put records that associate with a specific child class into a child class object.

I tried retrieving a list of records into a parent class list and casting them from the parent object to the child with a child cast, but of course , Java does not allow this during run time. (looks all pretty during compile time though)

I also tried to query with child class into a list of child classes but the only properties with values are the ones in the child class. All of the properties corresponding to the parent class are null even though the child extends the parent.

How can i query the table into an extended child class. I need to access members of the child class after I do this.

```
@DBTableMap ( dbTable = "TABLE_MINE", dbTableAlias = "tableDef" )
public class ParentDefined extends BaseData {

@DBPrimaryKey ( dbColumn = "id" )
private Long id;
private String type;
....
}

@DBTableMap ( dbTable = "TABLE_MINE", dbTableAlias = "tableDef", includeParent = true )
public class ChildDefined extends ParentDefined {

public ChildDefined()
{
    setDiscriminator("a type 1");
}

private String name;
private String overrideName;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
}
public String getOverrideName() {
    return overrideName;
}
public void setOverrideName(String overrideName) {
    this.overrideName = overrideName;
}

}

<hibernate-mapping>

<subclass name="ChildDefined" 
      extends="ParentDefined"
      type-value="a type 1">

    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="overrideName" column="overrideName" type="string"/>
</subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="ParentDefined" 
      table="TABLE_MINE" 
      abstract="true" 
      type-value="0">

    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
<type column="type" type="string" length="256" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
```

```
List<ParentClass> parents = (query using parent class by id);
for(ParentDefined parent : parents){
     ChildDefined child = (ChildDefined) parent; //class cast exception
}

List<ChildClass> childs = (query using child class by id and type 1);
for(ChildDefined child : childs){
     child; //class object only has values in ChildDefined members. Members of ParentDefined are null;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code of your Entities so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please post the code of both of your classes.